# How to make an IF statement with conditions articulated with OR that stops as soon as the first True condition is reached?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Let's take an example :
I would like to check if the variable `s` is a string with length equal or less than 3. I tried the following :

```
if (not isinstance(s,str)) | (len(s)>3) :
    print("The value of s is not correct : must be a string, with length equal or less than 3")
```

But it is not correct as the code considers the second condition whatever the result of the first one. For example, with `s = 2`, the code returns the error :

```
object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I would have thought that since the first condition is `True`, that the rest of the line would not have been considered. How please could I get the code to run until the first `True` condition is reached?

Comment: Logical or and bitwise or are very different. What you want is the logical or, which in python is just `or` (the equivalent in C language would be `||`, notice there are two symbols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a bitwise or. use the keyword `or` instead.

The or will shortcircuit as you correctly mention in your question, so if `s` is not a string the second part will not evaluate, preventing the error of trying to apply `len` to a non-string object.

```
if not isinstance(s, str) or len(s) > 3:
    print("The value of s is not correct : must be a string, with length equal or less than 3")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could you please explain when to use `|` and `or` ?

Comment: imagine a variable in bit representation `val = 0b00111001`   and you have another value, which we call a mask `mask = 0b11110000`. The bitwise or `|`, of the two, will compare bit by bit, and if one is true, that resulting bit will be true, not the whole result. In this case, the mask `11110000` sets the first 4 bits to 1 (no matter what the val bits are) and leave the last 4 bits as they are. so the result would be `0b11111001`. as you can see this as nothing to do with comparing two boolean values. It operates bits.

Comment: Very clear, thank you !